# Using BFS, is there a way to find the distance from all the vertices to the goal vertex?

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Let's say I have a simple graph A -> B -> C -> D. The edge weights are all 1. A is the starting vertex and D is the goal vertex. Using BFS, I can determine easily that the distance from A to D is 3.

Given that, I also want to find an efficient way to store the distances from B to D and from C to D, while the BFS-algorithm traverses the graph(starting at A and ending at D). I would prefer doing that with BFS combined with something like memoisation/ Dynamic Programming.

PS: My implementation of the BFS determines the neighbours of every vertex v **after** v gets popped from the queue. Therefore, it's not possible to go backwards in the graph, i.e. from D to A.

Comment: Despite your postscript, the way to do this is BFS from the goal vertex, going backwards along arcs (or reversing them before you start)

Comment: You need to make a copy of the graph with edges reversed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distance from A to D is the same as the distance from D to A after reversing the direction of all the arcs. Simply build a transpose graph and then run a BFS from D until you reach every node and record the distances. Some pseudocode would look like this:

```
distances = {}
visited = {source_node}

frontier = queue([(target_node, 0)])
while !frontier.empty():
    node, distance = frontier.pop()
    distances[node] = distance
    for nei in node.neighbors:
        if nei not in visited:
            frontier.push((nei, distance + 1))
            visited.insert(nei)
```

And at the end you'll have a map `distances`, where `distances[node]` is the distance from `node` to the target vertex.

Note that in BFS you don't need to ever go backwards. Going backwards is never going to find the shortest path since you're adding extra distance to get to each target.